# Update multiple solr servers at same time

Tags: solr, solrj

We have three Solr servers with the exact data on three of them. I wanted to update them at the same time when I run the script on one of the servers. Can I use a proxy to update the other two servers in Java(SolrJ)? Has anyone done this before?

Comment: The usual tactic if you're not using SolrCloud (which would handle replication for you) is to simply send the update request to all servers and confirm that the change has happened afterwards. You'll have a slight delay until all servers are in sync (since commit times will differ between servers ever so slightly)

Comment: The problem is that we have millions of documents to update. and every update would have a batch of 50,000 documents. and as this data exposed to clients, It needs to update exact same time

Comment: You can't guarantee that different nodes will have the _exact_ (within some value) same delay in making searchers available with new data. A possible solution is to make the updates to a separate collection, then switch all the collection / core aliases at almost the same time - that will probably give you the closest to any change being seen  simultaneous from all nodes. You'll have to define what "exact same time" means; how big is the interval which would be considered "same time"? 0.1s? 1s? 10s? a minute?

Comment: I am thinking to use SolrCloud. I am pretty new to it. can you give me some idea how can we achieve this using solrCloud?

Comment: It'll be done automagically for you. You only define certain properties of your collection, such as replicationFactor (how many servers it should be replicated to).

Comment: As you advised, I have configured solrCloud. but the performance of solrCloud for adding documents is really slow. for example, ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient was taking 1 or 2 minutes to insert 100000 documents, while CloudSolrClient is taking 10-20 minutes. How can I increase the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do this manually. You are reinventing Solr features.

For data with infrequent updates, maybe once per day, use a master server and a set of query (slave) servers that replicate the index. The replicas will check for changes on a schedule, maybe once per hour or every 15 minutes.

For frequent updates, use Solr Cloud. An update sent to any node in the cluster will automatically be forwarded to the leader for that shard. It will be indexed their and replicas will be notified to fetch it and index it on the replicas.

Solr cannot guarantee that updates will be simultaneous on all replicas. Solr is *not* a database and updates are *not* transactional. If you want transactions, use a database.

Comment: I have configured solrCloud. but the performance of solrCloud for adding documents is really slow. for example, ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient was taking 1 or 2 minutes to insert 100000 documents, while CloudSolrClient is taking 10-20 minutes. How can I increase the performance?